# Selective Summation inside the case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using sum function inside case statement. I want to do selective summation of rows.

```
case when
type in ('A','B')
then nvl(SUM(Amount_1),Amount)
else Amount
```

Two columns are there Amount and Amount_1 and for the Amount_1 column, I want to remove few rows based on some condition C1. For e.g. If I have 10 rows that have type in A and based on condition C1 I am getting only 8 rows then I want to sum Amount_1 column on the basis of 8 rows only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the basic logic understood correctly, but your syntax is a bit off.  You should be using the `CASE` expression *inside* the `SUM()` function, not the other way around.

```
SELECT type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('A', 'B')
                THEN COALESCE(Amount_1, Amount) ELSE Amount END) AS type_sum  -- ELSE 0 ?
FROM yourTable
```

This will compute the sum of `COALESCE(Amount_1, Amount)` for those records where the `type` is either `A` or `B`, otherwise it will use `Amount` in the sum.  If you intended to not count non-matching records at all, then modify my query by using `ELSE 0` in the `CASE` expression.